# Generating animation in the browser using matplotlib

Tags: python, html, matplotlib, jupyter, mpld3

Let me describe the background first:

We have a python package that uses matplotib to create animations.

Currently, we use this package to create gifs, which we embed into our website.
In the future, the number of animations will increase, so that we are looking for a way to create these gifs only dynamically when a user wants to see a gif. Preferably, these animations will be created in the browser using the CPU of the user. I have seen that mpld3 can be used to create visualizations, however, animations are not supported and it is using our CPU.

This leads me to the question: Does someone know about a way to generate animations from matplotlib code in the browser preferably using the CPU of the user (not a must have)? Maybe is there a way of using jupyter notebooks for that?

Comment: Matplotlib works in python; so in order to create an animation with matplotlib, python needs to run somewhere. If the user has installed python they could be provided some code to run for themselves, but otherwise you need to provide the server to run the python code.

Comment: Take a look at this blog http://jakevdp.github.io/blog/2013/12/19/a-d3-viewer-for-matplotlib/